# Trying to create new column using pyspark with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataset and in that dataset i have X and Y column

- X.dtype : timestamp
- Y.dtype: string

i want to make a Z column which has count value of unique Y column values. But it has to count before than the X time column for each row.

example dataset :

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-08 | number1 |
| 2021-09-09 | number2 |
| 2021-09-10 | number2 |
| 2021-09-11 | number3 |
| 2021-09-12 | number2 |
| 2021-09-13 | number2 |
| 2021-09-14 | number3 |

example result dataset :

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-08 | number1 | 0 |
| 2021-09-09 | number2 | 0 |
| 2021-09-10 | number2 | 1 |
| 2021-09-11 | number3 | 0 |
| 2021-09-12 | number2 | 2 |
| 2021-09-13 | number2 | 3 |
| 2021-09-14 | number3 | 1 |

Note : The X column is not sorted on original dataset and i dont want to sort X column.

Comment: `Note : The X column is not sorted on original dataset and i dont want to sort X column.` This sentence has no meaning. You're working with a distributed system. Lines in the dataframe does not have any order but you will have to order that column at one moment to get your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with a `row_number`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.withColumn(
    "z",
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("y").orderBy("x")) - 1
).show()
```